# Base UIViewController for entire app with views inside

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I want to create base view controller for my app, all other view controllers will subclass it. It will contain some controls inside.
How I can achieve that? For creating design, should I drag new View controller on storyboard and don't connect it anywhere (then You have warning all the time). i Would like to create outlets and make some base implementation. If I use xib file it don't have all guidelines, like one below status bar.

Comment: When you create the scene for your sub view controller. If you settle custom class to your subclass then you should see the outlets that are defined in the subclass and the superclass. You will need to add the controls to each scene and associate them with the outlets

Comment: But first I want to make layout with autolayout, should I use xib file or just drag nonconnected controller to storyboard? Just entry point (base controller will have simple status bar on top of screen that all my views have to have).

Comment: Have you looked into [child view controllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html)?

Comment: @Preetygeek. I don't understand your comment. You either use storyboard or nibs. Losiowaty has a good idea. It sounds like you should use a container view

Comment: @Losiowaty container view is not the best option. I'll try to figure it myself.